# startActivityForResult cannot find onActivityResult from a tab

Tags: android

I am developing a softphone with tabs, my problems is i want pick a contact on click of a button, everything is working fine i am developing this without tab .i.e. application without having tab, i find here many such problem but none of that is solving my problem.

here is code for pick contact

```
private static final int PICK_CONTACT = 0;


pickContactButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                    Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                    getParent().startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
    });
```

here is onActivityResult

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ 
      System.out.println("inside onActivityResult........");
      super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
   switch(reqCode){

      case (0):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Uri contactData = data.getData();
            Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
         if (c.moveToFirst()){
         String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

         String hasPhone =
         c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

         if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
         ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
           phones.moveToFirst();
           String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           //setCn(cNumber);
           System.out.println("cNumber: " + cNumber);
         }
        }
      }
   }
  }
```

problem is startActivityForResult never called onActivityResult

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);` instead of `getParent().startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);`

Comment: i did it before, result is same

Comment: is the activity started, but not calling onActivityResult()?

Comment: exactly thats the case @helleye

Comment: and in such a case you know it is not called because you don't see "inside onActivityResult........" printed, but it is printed when you don't use tabs? btw why don't you use Log class for logging?

Comment: normally i do that , i was just checking it in logcat of eclipse this time, so i did. next time when i will take consideration.

Comment: can you also show where do you call `pickContactButton.setOnClickListener(...)`, from which method and class, and in which class is the implementation of `onActivityResult()` ?

Comment: both pickContactButton.setOnClickListener(...) and onActivityResult() are called from same class which is class dialer,                                               `_ intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Dialer.class);
      spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("Dialer").setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec)_`                                                                                  pickContactButton.setOnClickListener(...) called from onCreate of dialer class

Comment: 1. So I assume this class dialer is an Activity  
2. in such a case you really need to remove that `getParent().`

Comment: 1. yes dialer is an activity 2. i remove getParent()     result is same

Comment: why is it `public` and not `protected void onActivityResult()`?

Comment: You are not calling startActivityForResult() in some kind of Fragment and override onActivityResult in Activity, Am I correct?

Comment: @Hellboy i am using android.app.LocalActivityManager which is not some kind of fragment or fragmentManger, i think

Comment: but are you calling startActivityForResult + override onActivityResult in that class?

Comment: for me is a classic problem that you call startActivityForResult and override onActivityResult in different "context"

Comment: i run the code with Override and w/o Override, what is mean by different "context" here.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the `PICK_CONTACT` constant? Make sure that `PICK_CONTACT = 0`.

Comment: don't you mean PICK_CONTACT != 0?

Answer (score -1):

Are you Overriding the method `onActivityResult()`?
if not, make sure to add the `@Override` annotation in your method.

Comment: Don't you think? it is happening because of the tabs, otherwise everything is fine with simple activity.

Comment: What do you want me to think, if you arent even able to write all of your code... Nice going trying to get help,my friend.

Comment: You don't have to have @Override annotation ;)

Comment: @Hellboy I don't think google would put an annotation in their examples if it was unnecessary...

Comment: @MateusBrandao
Method in extended class with the same name and params as in extending class is still overrided with or without `@Override` annotation.
The annotation itself helps the compiler check if you are actually override a method when you think you are. If you write `@Override` annotaiton in method which in fact is not overriding a parent method you will get error. Check it for youreself, remove all override annotation in your Activity, it will still work :) Know language you use not only framework. If you will have further question I would love to answer them, Cheers!